# Head and everything except Head?

Tags: syntax, expression-manipulation

I have been working on picking expressions apart using `Head` and `Part` and encountered a little mystery.  Consider the canonical example

```
a + b + c
```

which has `FullForm`

```
Plus[a, b, c]
```

We expect, then, `(a+b+c)[[0]] === Plus === Head[a+b+c]` to be `True`, and it is. But then, we would expect `(a+b+c)[[1;;3]]` would be `{a, b, c}`, wouldn't we?  But it isn't. The following is true:

```
(a + b + c)[[1;;3]] === (a + b + c)
```

Somehow, `[[1;;3]]`, which is supposed to pick off elements `1` through `3` of its argument and put them in a `List`, *doesn't* get rid of the `Head`, which is element `0`!

The questions are, then (and I will be grateful for hints and answers!)

1. Why doesn't `(a + b + c)[[1;;3]]` get rid of `(a + b + c)[[0]]`, the `Head`?
2. What is the right way to get rid of the `Head`?
3. `(a + b + c)[[0;;3]]` produces `0`.  I would expect it to produce `{Plus, a, b, c}`.  Instead, it produces `0`.  This just deepens the mystery for me!  Why?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### Point #1

`Part` always wraps element sequences with the original head of the expression.

```
expr = Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2, 3 + 3, 4 + 4, 5 + 5];

expr[[{2, 3}]]
```

> ```
> Hold[2 + 2, 3 + 3]
> ```

For this purpose a single part e.g. `1` is not a sequence but `{1}` and `1 ;; 1` are:

```
expr[[1]]

expr[[{1}]]

expr[[1 ;; 1]]
```

> ```
> 2
>
> Hold[1 + 1]
>
> Hold[1 + 1]
> ```

This applies at every level of the extraction:

```
exp2 = g[h[1, 2], i[3, 4]];

exp2[[  2 , 1  ]]
exp2[[ {2}, 1  ]]
exp2[[  2 ,{1} ]]
exp2[[ {2},{1} ]]
```

> ```
> 3
>
> g[3]
>
> i[3]
>
> g[i[3]]
> ```

I used this nontrivially for [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17553/121).

### Point #2

Consider instead using `Extract` which wraps sequences in `List`:

```
Extract[expr, {{2}, {3}}]
```

> ```
> {4, 6}
> ```

The third argument of `Extract` can be used to specify a function to apply to individual elements before they are evaluated:

```
Extract[expr, {{2}, {3}}, HoldForm]
```

> ```
> {2 + 2, 3 + 3}
> ```

If you want all parts you can also use `Level`:

```
Level[(a + b + c), {1}, Heads -> True]
```

> ```
> {Plus, a, b, c}
> ```

Or `Cases`:

```
Cases[(a + b + c), _, Heads -> True]
```

> ```
> {Plus, a, b, c}
> ```

Or `Replace`/`ReplaceAll`:

```
(a + b + c) /. head_[body___] :> {head, body}
```

> ```
> {Plus, a, b, c}
> ```

### Point #3

The last point is more tricky and I had to check it myself.  There is a behavior that I also did not expect:

```
Range[5][[0 ;; 5]]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

What I *expected* was an error as seen here:

```
Range[5][[0 ;; 4]]
```

and here:

```
Range[5][[0 ;; 6]]
```

When `Span` is used in `Part[x, 0 ;; n]` where `n` is the length of `x`, `Part` returns the head of the expression.  Therefore `(a + b + c)[[0;;3]]` returns `Plus[]` and `Plus[]` evaluates to `0`.

---

I believe `Span` behaves this way because of how it handles non-positive values, and zero-length spans.  Consider:

```
Range[10][[-2 ;; 10]]
```

> ```
> {9, 10}
> ```

You can see that it wraps around.  Now consider:

```
Range[10][[5 ;; 4]]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

An empty span returns the head of the expression with no arguments.

Using `0 ;; n` where `n` is the last element in the list, or `0 ;; -1`, is also an empty span wrapping around the open end of the list.

```
Range[10][[0 ;; -1]]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Comment: Ah, I see that you can answer #1 as well, not just Leonid :)

Comment: Regarding point #3, you might find [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/uniXhv_bcsY/discussion) relevant (if not too enlightening).

Comment: @Szabolcs That's important information.  I cannot recall a situation where it would affect me, but it would be bloody annoying to track it down if it did.

Comment: And another place for the all-powerful `Cases`: `Cases[{a + b + c}, head_[args___] -> {head, args}]` produces `{{Plus, a, b, c}}`

Comment: @Reb doing that route you don't even need `Cases`:  `a + b + c /. head_[args___] :> {head, args}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard +1 yields good answer !

Comment: @Artes Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps only the developers (or Leonid) can answer #1 and #3 and "why".

The quick answer to #2 is `Apply`, remembering that `List` is a `Head` like any other:

```
List @@ (a + b + c)
```

> `{a, b, c}`

On #3, I can't explain *why* `;;` syntax gives 0 when

```
(a + b + c)[[Range[0, 3]]]
```

gives

> `a + b + c + Plus`

So you could try

```
List @@ ((a + b + c)[[Range[0, 3]]])
```

> `{a, b, c, Plus}`

Comment: There is something broken in the way the site previews answers.  I have been amending my answer for the last twenty minutes and only *now* do I see that you also posted an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You don't get notified of a new answer when editing your already existing answer...

Comment: The List @@ answer has a deep, hackish charm, coming closest to answering "... and everything but Head.". The Extract and Level answers have more versatility and clearly enable complete analysis and compilation of expressions.  A metacircular evaluator for MMA would not seem too remote a possibility.

Comment: @R.M I would expect that when you save the edit to your post, the page would refresh, showing any new answers that were posted while you were working.  This is not the case.

Comment: In some sense, `Sequence@@(a+b+c)` comes closer to "everything but `Head`" than `List@@(a+b+c)`: While `List` is just another head (with a special input/display syntax associated with it), `Sequence` is the closest Mathematica has to a headless expressions: If you insert it anywhere (except functions with attribute `HoldAllComplete`) it just gets interpolated.

Comment: @celtschk For completeness the attribute `SequenceHold` also prevents the flattening of `Sequence` expressions, just as `HoldAllComplete` does, while allowing other evaluation.