# How to make a defined symbol stay in symbol form?

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, variable-definitions, symbols

How to make a defined symbol stay in symbol form?

```
w = 3; g = 4;

{w, g}[[2]]
```

> `3`

I want the output to be **`g`** and not `3`. For example, if I want to save different definitions by `DumpSave` in different files like below:

`Table[DumpSave["/Users/simonlausen/Desktop/Input/ex"<>ToString[i]<>".mx",
                    {w,g}[[i]]],{i,1,2}]`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to clear the numerical value? Clear[g] would do this.

Comment: You can probably also put Block[{w,g}, ***  ] around the expression above, to temporarily have no values for w and g

Comment: You might want to restrain yourself giving ownvalues to such symbols. Use them rather in local replacements like: `Clear[w, g]; (w + g)/. {w->1, g->2}`. So if you want the unevaluated symbol form, you can always write `{w, g}[[2]]` to get `g`.

Comment: I was hoping the question was about conveniently getting a symbol that has a value, without evaluating it. One may think of using Symbol there, which is not convient, or ToExpression["Hold[symb]"], which is ugly, but ToExpression["symb", InputForm, Hold] seems reasonable.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom: that exactly what my question was about. But I haven't found a solution to my second question: How to use a function like DumpSave without manually typing the name of symbol: DumpSave["dir/file.mx",data1] - works fine, but DumpSave["dir/file.mx",{data1,data2,data3}[[1]]] does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to sacrifice *something*, but it depends on your preferences *what* you want to keep and what you want to give up. Let's assume you don't want to sacrifice being able to use assignments such as `w=3`, then you may have to give up using `{...}` as a wrapper grouping the *names* of the variables together. You could then define a new wrapper `myList` to be used instead of `{...}`:

```
w = 3; g = 4;

myList[x__] := {ReleaseHold[HoldForm /@ Hold[x]]}

SetAttributes[myList, HoldAll]

myList[w, g][[2]]
```

> `g`

This is done by wrapping all elements of `myList` in `HoldForm`. You can retrieve the values of these held expressions by applying `ReleaseHold` to them.

**Edit**

To address the question about `DumpSave`, we have to modify the strategy a little:

```
myList[x__] := {ReleaseHold[Unevaluated /@ Hold[x]]}

Table[
 DumpSave["ex" <> ToString[i] <> ".mx", #] &[myList[w, g][[i]]], {i, 
  1, 2}]

(* ==> {{3}, {4}} *)
```

Here, I replaced `HoldForm` by `Unevaluated` in `myList`, so that the symbols `g` and `w` are now wrapped by it and will also print with that wrapper. The list of `DumpSave` commands in the `Table` then can take these unevaluated arguments as input. However, since `DumpSave` itself has attribute `HoldRest`, it wouldn't evaluate these wrappers either. So instead I feed them into `DumpSave` using the anonymous function `... #]& [..]` which doesn't obey the `HoldRest` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work, when I'm trying to use e.g. DumpSave. Actually I was trying to make a function that would convert a directory of csv files into mx files.

Comment: I didn't get what your goal was initially, but I think now the `DumpSave` should work.

Comment: I tried to run the function but get this: DumpSave::bsnosym: 3 is not defined as a symbol or a context. >>
DumpSave::bsnosym: 4 is not defined as a symbol or a context. >>
{DumpSave["ex1.mx", Unevaluated[3]], 
 DumpSave["ex2.mx", Unevaluated[4]]}

Comment: You probably forgot to copy the line  `SetAttributes[myList, HoldAll]`

Comment: That's right... Sorry. And thank you again. I think, that I'm beginning to understand it now...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this answer does not have much added value over that of Jens, but I'll post it anyway. As a remark about the part of the question about DumpSave, an alternative method to that of Jens is the following. I find that in cases where things get evaluated that you don't want to get evaluated, it helps to temporarily replace the function that you want to "do in the end", in this case DumpSave, by Hold. Then in the end you can replace the hold by your function (DumpSave) by using apply (@@). In this case you would proceed as follows

```
myList2 = {Hold[w], Hold[g]};

Table[
 DumpSave @@
  Delete[
   Hold[Evaluate[
     "/Users/simonlausen/Desktop/Input/ex" <> ToString[iii] <> ".mx", 
     myList[[iii]]]]
   ,
   {2, 0}
   ]
 ,
 {iii, 1, 2}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacob. I can see, that there are many ways to do the job...

Comment: @SimonLausen No problem. I guess i learned something new too :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
w = 3; g = 4;

HoldForm[w, g][[{2}]]
```

> ```
>  g   (* wrapped in HoldForm *)
> ```

The `{}` brackets are critical.  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2450/121) for an explanation.

---

I just read Jens' answer and now realize I missed an important part of the question.  I would do something similar to what he did, but I would write it a bit differently:

```
Table[
 DumpSave["path" <> ToString[i] <> ".mx", #] & @ {Unevaluated[w, g]}[[1, {i}]],
 {i, 1, 2}
]
```

Ignore the syntax highlighting in `Unevaluated[w, g]`.