# Is there a summary of answers Head[] can give?

Tags: functions

Sometimes you need to check for the type of an expression. You use Head[data] to get answers.

Some data:

```
data = {7, 1.4, Red, "hp", hps};
Head /@ data
(*{Integer, Real, RGBColor, String, Symbol}*)
```

Is there summary of what kind of answers `Head[]` can give?

Comment: I see that you have not [Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158428) my answer.  If you find it lacking please tell me in which way, so that I may improve it.  If it is not lacking please consider Accepting it.

Comment: see [here](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46473/if---) for a good summary :)

Answer (score 24):

`Head` can return any head.  There is no predefined list.

```
expr = myArbitraryHead[1, 2, 3];

Head[expr]
```

> ```
> myArbitraryHead
> ```

A head does not even need to be a Symbol:

```
expr2 = (2 Pi)[x, y, z];

Head[expr2]
```

> ```
> 2 π
> ```

Most heads are shown explicitly in the `FullForm` of the expression:

```
FullForm[{"a" + "b", 1/3}]

Head /@ {"a" + "b", 1/3}
```

> ```
> List[Plus["a", "b"], Rational[1, 3]]
>
> {Plus, Rational}
> ```

Some heads are implicit, such as in the atomic objects String, Integer, and Symbol:

```
FullForm[{"a", 1, Pi}]

Head /@ {"a", 1, Pi}
```

> ```
> List["a", 1, Pi]
>
> {String, Integer, Symbol}
> ```

---

As a side note the head of an expression is also returned when you ask for `Part` zero:

```
3[[0]]
```

> ```
> Integer
> ```

Because `Part` [returns sequences wrapped in the original head](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/head-and-everything-except-head/2450#2450) of the expression you get a strange result if extracting `{0}`:

```
3[[{0}]]
```

> ```
> Integer[Integer]
> ```

Comment: +1 Also, for atomic data types (`Integer`, `Rational`, etc. and some more, e.g. `Graphs`) it returns the *type* rather than the *head*. Though it is more of a philosophical question what the differences is between type and head in *Mathematica*.

Comment: +1 Mr.Wizard introducing terminology is nice.

Comment: I voted for your answer, but I disagree with the hidden head part. We should not use `StandardForm` (or, rather, you probably meant particular formatting which visually looks as if we had a division) for determination of heads and other structural components. Let's apply Occam's razor principle and not multiply entities unnecessarily. As to implicit heads, this is probably ok, but even here I am not sure - those are really the heads of certain atomic types, and there are just very few of those - basically they exist because the syntax allows for string and numeric literals.

Comment: @Leonid I think I understand your point about "hidden" heads, and I agree that was a poor choice (and will be edited).  As for implicit heads how would you state it?

Comment: I'd just say that atomic types represented as string or numeric literals also have heads (as any expression in Mathematica), but these heads are assigned to them internally and don't follow from their `FullForm` representation. This refers to `Integer`, `Real`, `String` and `Symbol` (not sure if I forgot some). Something like that.

Comment: @Leonid I edited this 10 hours ago with that intention; how does it read to you?

Comment: Sorry, I only read the comment. I think it is pretty good now.