# Scan vs. Map vs. Apply

Tags: functions, expression-manipulation, core-language, functional-style, function-comparison

I cannot understand the difference between  `Apply`, `Scan`, and `Map`.

I have tried to play with these functions using the codes below:

```
f[x_] := x^2
```

---

```
Map[f, {{a, b}, c}]
```

Output:

```
{{a^2, b^2}, c^2}
```

---

```
 Apply[f, {{a, b}, c}]
```

Output:

```
f[{a, b}, c]
```

---

```
Scan[f, {{a, b}, c}]
```

There is no output for this one.

The function of `Map` is understandable. But I cannot get the purpose of `Apply` and `Scan`. What are the differences between these three functions?

Comment: Do *not* define `f` when you do this, then it'll be much easier to understand what's going on.  `...^2` threads over lists so your results don't reflect only the effect of `Map`, etc. but also this auto-threading.  Take a look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/) and in the documentation page of each function.  There are plenty of examples.  For example the documentation clearly explains that `Scan` is the same as `Map` except it doesn't return anything.  If is useful when `f` has a side-effect, e.g. `f=Print`.

Comment: In addition to the references given by @Szabolcs: I covered these functions in considerable detail [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node53.html).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

These three functions are similar (speaking commonly), and in some applications any of them could be used, yet they have very different special applications.

Rudimentarily:

- [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) *wraps* (sub)expressions in a given Head, and returns the modified input
- [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) *replaces* Heads in (sub)expressions, and returns the modified input
- [`Scan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Scan.html) *"visits"* (sub)expressions, evaluates each of them, and returns [`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Null.html)

(For each example below `f` should be undefined; start with `ClearAll[f]`.)

### Map

Most basically `Map` works like this:

```
f /@ head[1, 2, 3]      (* shorthand for Map[f, head[1, 2, 3], {1}] *)
```

> ```
> head[f[1], f[2], f[3]]
> ```

As with each of the functions under discussion it can operate at different levels:

```
Map[f, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {0}]
Map[f, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {1}]
Map[f, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {2}]
Map[f, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {0, 2}]
```

> ```
> f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
>
> {f[{1, 2}], f[{3, 4}]}
>
> {{f[1], f[2]}, {f[3], f[4]}}
>
> f[{f[{f[1], f[2]}], f[{f[3], f[4]}]}]
> ```

`Map` is an additive process; it inserts additional heads into an expression at the specified [*levelspec*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29752/121) and then evaluates it.

If the expression is held nothing evaluates.  (Held meaning the outermost Head has an Attribute such as [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html).  [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hold.html) has this attribute.  Do not confuse the Head with the Attribute.)

```
Print /@ Hold[a[1, 2], b[3, 4]]
```

> ```
> Hold[Print[a[1, 2]], Print[b[3, 4]]]
> ```

### Apply

`Apply` works like `Map`, except that instead of adding a Head it replaces an existing one, if a head exists at the specified level.  Unlike `Map` it is frequently used at *levelspec* `{0}` with the short form `@@`, which replaces the outermost head:

```
f @@ head[1, 2, 3]   (* short form of Apply[f, head[1, 2, 3], {0}] *)
```

> ```
> f[1, 2, 3]
> ```

A second short form (`@@@`) exists for *levelspec* `{1}`:

```
f @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> ```
> {f[1, 2], f[3, 4]}
> ```

If a sub-expression is atomic (has no operable Head) `Apply` does not modify it:

```
f @@@ head[1, 2, x + y]
```

> ```
> head[1, 2, f[x, y]]
> ```

Note that `1` and `2` are unmodified, while `x + y` (which has a [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html) of `Plus[x, y]`) had its Head replaced.

As with `Map`, `Apply` transforms an expression and then evaluates it in entirety; if it is held evaluation does not continue:

```
Print @@@ Hold[a[1, 2], b[3, 4]]
```

> ```
> Hold[Print[1, 2], Print[3, 4]]
> ```

One way to "release" this expression for evaluation is to replace `Hold` with something else, like [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/List.html):

```
List @@ Print @@@ Hold[a[1, 2], b[3, 4]]
```

> 12
>
> 34
>
> ```
> {Null, Null}
> ```

Note here that the elements `1`, `2`, and `3`, `4` are printed by [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Print.html), but since `Print[. . .]` itself evaluates to `Null` the *output* of the line is `{Null, Null}`.

### Scan

`Scan` is also like `Map`, except that each individual expression which is wrapped in the specified head is evaluated outside of the main expression, and the main expression is never returned.  If we `Scan` a function without side-effects over an expression we get nothing:

```
Scan[f, head[1, 2, 3]]
```

(This could also be written `f ~Scan~ head[1, 2, 3]`.) We do not even get an output line because the output is `Null` and *Mathematica* does not print a lone `Null` output line (by convention).  If we use a function with side-effects, such as `Print`, we get a different result:

```
Scan[Print, head[1, 2, 3]]
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

Crucially `Scan` will carry out its evaluation even when an expression is held because it only looks at the subexpressions:

```
Print ~Scan~ Hold[a[1, 2], b[3, 4]]
```

> a[1,2]
>
> b[3,4]

Its evaluation can also be interrupted because, unlike `Map` and `Apply` which transform the entire expression, then evaluate it, `Scan` works incrementally:

```
(Print[#]; If[# > 2, Return[]]) & ~Scan~ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

Because `Scan` does not first duplicate and then modify the entire expression it may be more memory efficient than the use of `Map` or `Apply`, but it will still unpack packed arrays therefore if memory efficiency is a priority other methods may be preferred.

---

### Conclusion

I hope these simple examples illustrate that these three functions, while closely related, have unique characteristics that differentiate their use, and each has powerful applications that the others do not.

Recommended reading regarding performance of these and related functions:

- [Two ways of map a function on the list: Which one is faster?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35150/121)
- [Choose between `Apply` and `Map`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70201/121)

---

#### Notes on atomic objects

Not all expressions that have the appearance `head[arguments]` in [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html) are actually standard expressions in that form that can be manipulated with structural tools such as `Apply`.  Instead they have a special internal format and they are merely *displayed* in the form `head[arguments]`.

From the documentation on [Atomic Objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BasicObjects.html#15871):

> All expressions in Mathematica are ultimately made up from a small
>   number of basic or atomic types of objects.
>
> These objects have heads that are symbols that can be thought of as
>   "tagging" their types. The objects contain "raw data", which can
>   usually be accessed only by functions specific to the particular type
>   of object. You can extract the head of the object using Head, but you
>   cannot directly extract any of its other parts.

Standard objects such as strings and integers are atomic, but so are other expressions that may not appear to be:

```
list = {1, "test", 1/2, 2 + 3 I};
list // FullForm
AtomQ /@ list
```

> ```
> List[1, "test", Rational[1, 2], Complex[2, 3]]
>
> {True, True, True, True}
> ```

Also atomic are more complex structures such as [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html), [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graph.html), [`BooleanFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BooleanFunction.html), and (in recent versions) [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image.html).

Atomic objects (or atoms) are handled differently from standard (compound) expression forms.

- `Rational[1, 2]` is atomic even though it appears otherwise.
- Even though `1` is formatted without an obvious head, [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html) will return `Integer`.
  (See [Is there a summary of answers Head[] can give?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22449/121) for other examples.)
- `Apply` does not work in the "normal" way on atoms:

  ```
  new @@@ list
  ```

  > ```
  > {1, "test", 1/2, 2 + 3 I}
  > ```
- [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html) and kin often work on the apparent `FullForm` of atoms:

  ```
  Replace[list, head_[args__] :> {head, args}, {1}]
  ```

  > ```
  > {1, "test", {Rational, 1, 2}, {Complex, 2, 3}}
  > ```
- Functions may be overloaded to handle atoms differently; e.g. many functions treat a `SparseArray` as they would the [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Normal.html) form expression:

  ```
  new @@ SparseArray[{1, 2, 3}]
  ```

  > ```
  > new[1, 2, 3]      (* not new[{1, 2, 3}] *)
  > ```
- Handling may appear somewhat irregular even within functions; [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) will "extract" (or return) the head of `Rationa[1, 2]` but not anything else:

  ```
  Part[1/2, 0]
  ```

  > ```
  > Rational
  > ```

  ```
  Part[1/2, 1]
  ```

  > Part::partd: Part specification (1/2)[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
  >
  > ```
  > (1/2)[[1]]
  > ```

(Somewhat related, and perhaps of interest: [Head and everything except Head?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/121))

Comment: Worth to link  [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7925/5478) I think you should now :P Quite [relevant](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/705/5478) but not closely related.

Comment: It may be worthwhile adding a note about things that are atomic, but not immediately obviously so, like `AtomQ@Complex[1, 1] == True` vs. `AtomQ@Complex[1, a] == False`. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Could you point me to an explanation for the syntax `f ~Scan~ head[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @Sascha It is infix notation.  Please see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html).  `a ~op~ b` is equivalent to `op[a, b]`.  I use it a lot because I find it more readable than many nested brackets, but I know a lot of people don't agree with me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nice! +1

Comment: @rcollyer I added a section on atoms.  I'm not sure this is the best place for it, but I couldn't think of a way to address the issues concisely yet adequately.

Comment: +1, nice answer. I'd perhaps emphasize more strongly that because `Scan` does not produce an output, it can be significantly more memory-efficient than `Map`, particularly when such an output is not needed and in discarded in any case. I've seen cases where this made a real difference.

Comment: @Leonid Thanks for the vote and suggestion; I'll try to better address that soon.

Comment: @Leonid I finally added a brief note on the memory use of `Scan`.  A deeper analysis could be given but it seems out of place here.  Does this still address your point?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is interesting. Somehow, I never realized that `Scan` unpacks, and this indeed makes a big difference. In practice then, for really large lists, it may make sense to have a chunked version of `Scan`, that would use `Map` (or Listability) on chunks. Of course, one then looses the ability to return from `Scan` at any point (inserting such a condition will break vectorization), but for many use cases that can be just fine. Thanks for this tidbit. So yes, it kind of addresses the issue, although it would be nice to have an example, as well as emphasize that `Scan` unpacks.

Comment: @Leonid I guess we all still get surprises now and then :^)  I have [recommended](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21589/121) a "block based" (you say chunked) method before, but for true iteration without unpacking I know of nothing better than a `Do` loop with `Part` over positions.  I'll think about an example if I can keep from getting too far off topic.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Unfortunately, due to the nature of `Do`, the by-element indexing method is slow to the degree that it defeats the purpose. Of course, in such cases for large numerical (packed) arrays there is always `Compile`, and for non-packed it doesn't matter that much. The good thing would be to systematically enumerate these approaches with their respective domains of applicability, pros and cons (I mean, Scan, Map, chunked scan based on Map, Do loop, Compile). Otherwise it is hard to keep all these things in mind, even for us.

Answer (score 15):

For a visual, animated, description of basic behavior of such functions, I recommend:

http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/

(You may want to turn on your computer's sound.)

Comment: As a rule we try to avoid link-only answers. (Excepting large collections.)  Perhaps you could include a screen capture or something?  Also, I don't see an animation for `Scan`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: The whole point is that the link points to *animations* of how the various operators work! And given that the pages are copyright by Wolfram Research, I'm not sure it's legal to post even a static screenshot (would it be "fair use"?) But the animations are *very* useful ways to understand what `Map`, `Apply`, etc., do -- using a different modality than the usual static examples.