# What does the expression "Total[funca[a,#] & /@ #] & /@ {x,y}" possibly mean?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pure-function, regular-expressions

Can the expression be simplified as "Total[funca[a,#]] & /@ {x,y}"?
What does the double of "& /@" mean? Where can I find some reference?

### Updated

According to [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard)'s answer, I now know the result. But I still can not understand the combination use of #&/@.

For example, the result from Out[1] to Out[6] looks so weird to me. Who can help to explain that?

```
x = {q, r, s};
y = {t, u, v};
In[1]:= Total[funca[a, #]] & /@ {x, y}
```

> Out[1]:= {{a + q, a + r, a + s}, {a + t, a + u, a + v}}

```
In[2]:= Total[funca[a, #] & /@ #] & /@ {x, y}
```

> Out[2]:= {funca[a, q] + funca[a, r] + funca[a, s], funca[a, t] + funca[a, u] + funca[a, v]}

```
In[3]:= Total[funca[a, #] & /@ # & /@ #] & /@ {x, y}
```

> Out[3]:= {q + r + s, t + u + v}

```
In[4]:= Total[{a, #}] & /@ {x, y}
```

> Out[4]:= {{a + q, a + r, a + s}, {a + t, a + u, a + v}}

```
In[5]:= Total[{a, #} & /@ #] & /@ {x, y}
```

> Out[5]:= {{3 a, q + r + s}, {3 a, t + u + v}}

```
In[6]:= Total[{a, #} & /@ # & /@ #] & /@ {x, y}
```

> Out[6]:= {q + r + s, t + u + v}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Total[funca[a,#] & /@ #] & /@ {x,y}
```

There are two [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) expressions here which I will refer to as inner and outer.  The inner function:

```
funca[a,#] &
```

Is [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)ped to the sole argument of the outer function.  It will transform a list or other expression like this:

```
funca[a,#] & /@ foo[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> foo[funca[a,1], funca[a,2], funca[a,3]]
> ```

The outer function does this to its single argument and then [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html)s it, which for the above would be:

```
funca[a,1] + funca[a,2] + funca[a,3]
```

- To clarify: in the snippet `funca[a,#] & /@ #` the left `#` (in `funca[a,#]`) will be filled by the argument of the inner function while the right `#` will be filled by the argument of the outer function.

This is done for each for `x` and `y` because it (the outer function) is also mapped across `{x, y}`.

A complete example:

```
x = {q, r, s};
y = {t, u, v};

Total[funca[a, #] & /@ #] & /@ {x, y}
```

> ```
> {funca[a, q] + funca[a, r] + funca[a, s],
>  funca[a, t] + funca[a, u] + funca[a, v]}
> ```

The operation could also be written:

```
Total /@ Map[funca[a, #] &, {x, y}, {2}]

Map[funca[a, #] &, {x, y}, {2}] ~Total~ {2}
```

Comment: ,Thank you. I know the result now but I still can not understand.

Comment: @xibinke maybe you just need to read: [what are those symbols?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/5478)

Comment: @xibinke Please read these documentation pages, then if you are still have trouble let me know: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html,
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html,
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html,

Comment: @xibinke Also please read my answer to [(46238)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121) as I explain `Map` (of which `/@` is the short form) in my own words.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you. Your answer really helps me a lot. Now I can understand the result of In[2]. Also I can understand In[1][4][5] after I realized that Total gives the sum of the first level of list. And what about In[3][6], seems meaningless?