# Tutorial for Map, Apply, etc

Tags: code-review, map

I have this code:

```
g1[x_] := 1;
g2[x_] := x;
g3[x_] := x^2;
norm[r_, s_] := Integrate[r[x] s[x] + r'[x] s'[x], {x, 0, 1}];
gram = {
        {norm[g1, g1], norm[g1, g2], norm[g1, g3]},
        {norm[g2, g1], norm[g2, g2], norm[g2, g3]},
        {norm[g3, g1], norm[g3, g2], norm[g3, g3]}
       }
```

Which returns:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{5}{4} \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{5}{4} & \frac{23}{15} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I wish I could do this computation using `Map` with just `g[x_]:= {1,x,x^2}` without loops, but I don't really understand the tricky *Mathematica* language for such things.  I don't really know if I should use `Apply` or `Map` or something else.

I have been using *Mathematica* for a while and I've tried to learn this kind of coding without loops but I'm still like the first day.  Watching the examples I saw here is not enough for me.  I just can see a bunch of `# /& @` without been able to understand it.  So I always ended avoiding this chapter.

Anyone knows any tutorial for **this particular matter**?

Comment: With respect to the title of the question, see section 5.2 of [Leonid Shifrin's book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org) or section 5.1 of [Robert Wagner's book](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat).

Comment: [On this site](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/) you can find some short animations explaining a few of Mathematica's basic commands (like Map and Apply).

Comment: You can read this answer of the Question [Scan vs Map vs Apply](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46238/scan-vs-map-vs-apply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
g[1][x_] := 1;
g[2][x_] := x;
g[3][x_] := x^2;
norm[r_, s_] := Integrate[r[x]*s[x] + r'[x]*s'[x], {x, 0, 1}];

gram=Array[norm[g[#1], g[#2]] &, {3, 3}]
```

or...

```
gram=Table[norm[a, b], {a, {g1, g2, g3}}, {b, {g1, g2, g3}}];
```

or...

```
gram=Outer[norm, {g1, g2, g3}, {g1, g2, g3}]
```