# How to map a function on a variable list

Tags: functional-style, map

The following is just an example that captures what I want to do (more on it at the bottom).

I'm trying to do something that can be paraphrased as follows:
I have a global list, say `list = {0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1}`. I have a function which can modify the global list:

```
f[element_] := (If[element == 1, list = Select[list, # != 1 &]]; counter++)
```

My problem is that when I map the function on the list, it goes through all the elements of the initial version of it, without skipping the values that have been eliminated:

```
counter = 0;
f /@ list;
counter
(* 9 *)
```

How do I get around this problem? (I'm ok with making the list locally defined)

**EDIT:**
From the comments I gather that it might be useful to explain what I actually want to do. Well, here it is. I have a quantum system which is transformed and it may incur in errors: my list is a list of possible errors. My function looks at the errors and determines if they are correctable or not. To save time, if an error $E$ is not correctable I want to skip those errors in the list that come from composing $E$ with others.

Comment: Is your goal to compute `counter`...? When you first hit an element that is 1 all the other 1s will not be selected, so what do you need the modified list for?

Comment: No, this is only an example. My function does much else on other objects in the meantime. My actual list is a list of possible errors on a quantum system and my function checks if they are correctable. If one is not correctable I want it to skip checking all the ones that "include it" because they must be uncorrectable as well.

Comment: Seems like your better off using `Select` on `list` rather than reassigning it lots of times inside `f`.

Comment: I would advise (not only in Mathematica) to avoid mutating state at all cost. As others have suggested better use `Select` and leave the original list intact or use `Sow` and `Reap` to build a list of results if you really have to do things iteratively.

Comment: I would be curious to know, what you are actually trying to do. It seems to me that your question is ill-posed.

Comment: My goal is not to compute the final list. I want to use the list as a set of inputs, which may change depending on the results of the function. Also, I don't want to mutate states *at all costs*, if there is a workaround I'll be very happy!

Comment: @Ziofil you may want to edit your question and clarify what your goal is. The code from your question leads one to believe you want to count the number of entries in a list that are not equal to 1

Comment: By the way, `/@` works as intended: First the right hand side is evaluated and then the function is applied to this (new) List. Changes to `list` have thus no effect on the result. See `Trace[f/@list]` for details.

Comment: So, basically, you want to stop after first 1?

Comment: Why do you need Map at all? You may just check if 1 is in the list? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ziofil Does my answer address your needs or did I miss the point?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding the nature of [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html).  It applies a head to a series of elements, then evaluates the complete expression.  Please see my answer to [Scan vs. Map vs. Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121) for examples and further description.

What you want might be handled by redefining `f` rather than redefining `list`.

```
ClearAll[f, list, counter]

f[element_] := (If[element == 1, f[1] = "skip"]; counter++)

list = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};

counter = 0;
f /@ list
counter
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, "skip", "skip", "skip", "skip"}
>
> 5
> ```

After the first instance of `f[1]` is evaluated a new definition `f[1] = "skip"` is added to the rule table.  Further evaluations of `f[1]` trigger that rule instead (because it is more specific) and do not increase the `counter`.  The new rule could also be pattern based, e.g.:

```
ClearAll[f, list, counter]

f[element_] := (If[element == 1, f[x_ /; x == 1] = x]; counter++)

list = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1.0, 1, 1};

counter = 0;
f /@ list
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1., 1, 1}
> ```

This returns unmodified any elements which match the [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) `x == 1`, after that rule is initially set by evaluation of the third element of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Scan` and `Return`.

`Return` from `f` after you reset the list.

```
f[element_] := (If[element == 1, list = Select[list, # != 1 &]; 
   Return[]]; counter++;)
```

Then `Scan` the function with the `Return` .

```
Scan[f, list]

counter
(* 4 *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you modify `list` for?

Comment: @Berg Using the OP's example function.

Comment: Wait, it should evaluate 4 times, no? There are 4 zeros.

Comment: Okay. One second.

Comment: What if I have the function `f` return the new list and I use `NestWhile` on it with the condition that `list` not be empty? As in `f[list_]:=Module[{el=First@list},If[el == 1, Return[ Select[list, # != 1 &]]]; counter++]` and then use `NestWhile[f,initialList,Length@#>0&]`

Comment: I updated it.  It will now scan only the values in the list not equal to one.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to manage the loop yourself, i.e.

```
list = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};

p = MapIndexed[Prepend[#2, #1] &, list];

f[{element_}] := (If[First[element] == 1, p = Select[p, First[#] != 1 &]]; counter++)

f[{}] := counter++

counter = 0;

Array[f[Cases[p, {_, #}]] &, Length[p]];

counter
```

> 9

```
list = Map[First, p]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0}