# Map over multidimensional matrix

Tags: matrix, map

Suppose I have a 8by6by4by2by2 matrix called `m`. There is in total 8*6*4 2by2 matrices. I want to map a function over these 2by2 matrices. Each dimension in `m` contains a 2by2 matrix for some specific parameters. My example code and solution is:

```
m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {8, 6, 4, 2, 2}];
m2 = Flatten[m, 2];(* 8*6*4 matrices of size 2by2*)
f[m_] := Total@Eigenvalues[m]
Map[f, m2]
```

However, then I cannot reconstitute the result in the original order of `m`.
Is there some other way to map over multidimensional matrices?

I have to reconstitute  the result of map in order to first average the result over first dimension, 8 here, and then plot the 6by4 matrix in a contour plot.

Comment: Use the third argument of `Map[]`: `Map[f, m2, {3}]`.

Comment: @J.M. I got confused about this level thing in `Map` , `Total` ... . Is there any source about that.

Comment: Apart from the docs, how about [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46238)?