# How to ScanThread and ScanIndexed?

Tags: functional-style, map

Why are there `MapThread` and `MapIndexed` but no analogous functions for `Scan`?

What is the recommended way to `Scan` over a pair of datasets (`ScanThread`), or over an ordered dataset (`ScanIndexed`)?

---

**Edit**

The reason I don't want to use `Map` is because it builds up an expression, which wastes memory and time.

I need to apply function(s) `f`, `g` with no output (only side effects) on lists of entries:

```
data1 = {a,b,c,d,e};
data2 = {s,t,u,v,w};

(*MapThread correctly calls f[a,s], f[b,t], but builds up an expression*)
MapThread[f, {data1, data2}] 

(*MapIndexed calls g[a,{1}], g[b,{2}], but builds up an expression*)
MapIndexed[g, data1]
```

I only want to scan over these entries, without wasting resources and time.

Comment: You can use `Map*` versions and just add `;` it will be close, those rules apply: [46238](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/5478)

Comment: Do you have a use case in which the `Scan` behavior is preferable to `Map`?

Comment: I think you owe us a better formulation of this question. Give us two example datasets and an example of a query which would require the function you propose.

Comment: @Kuba `Map` builds up an expression which wastes time and memory; I need `Scan` (see edit).

Comment: @MacroB `Map` builds up an expression which wastes time and memory; I need `Scan` (see edit)

Comment: `ScanIndexed` is on the road map, not sure when it will appear though.

Comment: @m_goldberg Added edit.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Ok that's good to know.  In the meantime, what is the recommended way to mimic a `ScanThread` and `ScanIndexed`?

Comment: Your edit isn't very helpful. We all know what `Map` and `MapThread` do. What we need are examples giving executable code. Real data and actual functions for which scanning would be better than mapping.

Comment: @m_goldberg Ok thanks; I guess I'm basically directing this question to those who already understand why and when `Scan` is preferable to `Map`; I just need to know from them what to do in those situations if I need the threaded and indexed versions of these functions.

Comment: @QuantumDot, I suspect that @m_goldberg *is* in fact familiar with `Scan` vs. `Map` use cases, but he is asking you as the author of the question to provide us with an actual code case where one can appreciate a significant difference between Scan and Map, rather than just the perception of waste, so we can evaluate different possible solutions in terms of time and memory consumption. If you don't provide that, you will only get answers from those that have had the problem, and solved it, which may rather significantly reduce your chances.

Comment: There is the undocumented ``GeneralUtilities`ScanIndexed``, but it is just a high-level wrapper that delegates to `Do`, `Scan` or sometimes even `MapIndexed`.

Comment: I agree with other comments that examples of your real life data and function would be useful, so we could do some meaningful benchmarks. For simplest case of indexed scanning you could just manually increment index: `Module[{i = 0}, Scan[f[#, {++i}] &, data1]]`

Comment: @WReach Interesting find!

Comment: @jkuczm Yes, that is a very helpful alternative; I think I'll use it.  Would you kindly add that as an answer?  (Also I thought for `ScanThread` the following `Scan[f@@#&, Transpose[{data1,data2}]]`; what do you think?)

Comment: @QuantumDot `Transpose[{data1,data2}]` creates new list of pairs, so most likely `MapThread[f, {data1, data2}];` or `MapThread[(f@##; 0) &, {data1, data2}];` will use same or less memory while being faster.

Comment: @jkuczm Oh, ok; thanks.