# Two-slot pure function

Tags: pure-function, arithmetic

I come across this problem in many different forms when doing arithmetic in MMA and have until now just suffered along doing it the long way – having given up trying to figure it out  myself – but now I have to admit that's getting a bit *repetitive*.

How does one get two slots working in a pure function? I'm trying to work out the % differences in the following list but it just returns can not be filled **errors**.

```
data={16,24,36,54,81};
(100*#2)/#1 &/@ Partition[data,2,1]
```

[image: sample image]

Comment: `(100*#[[1]])/(#[[2]]) & /@ p` where `p=Partition[data,2,1]` is one way

Comment: Okay that does work. :) Is there a way to use ``#1``/``#2`` directly from ``data``? Else the main big mystery remains.

Comment: I think `(100*#2)/#1 & @@@ p` is the cleanest way.

Comment: Compare the output of `f[#1, #2] & @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]` with that of `f[#] & /@ Partition[data, 2, 1]` (for undefined `f`). `@@@` replaces the head, `List`, of each sublist with `f`, whereas `/@` applies `f` to each sublist.

Comment: [Mr.Wizard's answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46248/45411) might be useful, too.

Comment: You need "apply at the first level", which is shorthanded `@@@`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `p=Partition[data,2,1]`, you can do any of the following :

```
(100*#2)/#1 & @@@ p   (* parsed as Apply[ (100*#2)/#1 &, p, {1} ] *)
Apply[ (100*#2)/#1 & ] /@ p
(100*#[[2]])/(#[[1]]) & /@ p  (* Credit to Nasser in the comments *)
```

All evaluate to `{150, 150, 150, 150}`.

---

Your original try failed because `Map` (`/@`) passes only one argument to the function -- for example, `#1` gets replaced by `{16,24}` for the first element of `p`.  You need to take parts of `#1` (which is equivalent to `#`), as in Nasser's example (the third example I included above), or you need to use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) to pass `16` and `24` as the first and second arguments, as you seem to desire.