# How to I use Map to apply a defined function to a list?

Tags: map

Problem: How to map a function onto a list.
My (example input:

```
mylist = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
gg[x_, y_] := {N[x + y], N[x y]}
Map[gg, mylist]
```

Expected output:

```
{{3., 2.}, {7., 12.}}
```

Actual output:

```
{gg[{1, 2}], gg[{3, 4}]}
```

How do I get `gg[.]` to give a numerical (function evaluated) output of `mylist`?

Comment: try `gg[{x_, y_}] := {N[x + y], N[x y]}`

Comment: `gg @@@ mylist`. But if you need to use `Map` then `Apply[gg] /@ mylist`.

Comment: [Scan vs. Map vs. Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/5478) - quite broad but should answer.

Comment: Not sure why, but that works. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments by [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478), you should use

```
gg @@@ mylist
```

Indeed, this is precisely raison d'être of `@@@`. If you want to use `Map`, then Kuba suggests to use the operator form of `@@`, to wit,

```
Apply[gg] /@ mylist
```

Finally, let me mention that if you insist on using `Map`, then you should redefine the function `gg` into (hat tip to [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125))

```
gg[{x__}] := {N[+x], N[1 x]}
```

If you do so, then `Map[gg, mylist]` yields your expected output.

Comment: Fun fact: the expression `Plus[x]` can be simplified into `+x`, but `Times[x]` cannot be replaced by `*x`. Seems inconsistent to me -- both `Plus` and `Times` are `OneIdentity`, and I'd expect both of them to behave similarly. Wonder why they don't here...

Comment: `{+##, 1 ##} & @@@ mylist` ?

Comment: @kglr Ah, perfect. I was actually about to post a question on why `*` is not allowed to be unary as opposed to `+`. Your trick works just fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
gg[x_, y_] := {N[x + y], N[x y]}
Map[gg[#[[1]],#[[2]]]&, mylist]
```