# Can I exit a Map over a list of data pairs?

Tags: map

I've written a function, which I intended to `Map` over lists of some 8,000 element pairs.

I created the "toy" code below to illustrate my problem.

```
yld = 0.0742;
pVal = 10000;
pVal2 = 10000;
dataPairs = {{a, 0.0027}, {b, 0.0027}, {c, 0.0027}, {d, 0.002}, {e, 0}, {f, 0.0027}, {g, 0.002}};

f[dataPairs_] :=  Module[{date, prem, pValX, preQ},
   prem = yld * dataPairs[[2]]*pVal2; 
   pValX = pVal2 + prem;
   preQ = Which[
     pVal >= pValX, True,
     pVal < pValX, False];
   {dataPairs[[1]], preQ}];

f[#] & /@ dataPairs
```

Which outputs:

```
{{a, False}, {b, False}, {c, False}, {d, False}, {e, True}, {f, False}, {g, False}}
```

I have 11,500 of these 8,000 element long lists.  It gets be a lot of run time.

From each of these lists, I really only need the mapping to run until I get a the first paired output with `True` in it, e.g., `{e, True}`.

On average I expect to get a `True`, within the first 1250 applications of the function (`f[]`) to each of the 8,000 element long lists.  If I can break the mapping when I first get `True`, it would vastly reduce the run time of the larger program.

Using `NestWhile` or `FoldWhile`, didn't seem to make sense because I don't need to build up iterative calculation on calculation.

I've considered `SelectFirst`, with the test for `True` as the criteria, but haven't had success.

Thoughts and suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `TakeWhile[list, Not@*Last]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

Edited to address a comment made by the OP. I seem to have lost sight of the original requirement stated in the question.

**Answer**

I don't think you can exit from [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), but the documentation points out that either [`Throw`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Throw.html) *or* [`Return`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return.html) may be used to exit from [`Scan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html).

This may be sufficient, or even the preferred option.

To [quote](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46248/106) (the much missed) [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard):

> [`Scan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html) "visits" (sub)expressions, evaluates each of them, and returns [`Null`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Null.html)
> [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) wraps (sub)expressions in a given Head, and returns the modified input

**Using** `Return`

```
Scan[If[f[#][[2]], Return[f@#]]&, dataPairs]

{e, True}
```

**Using** `Throw/Catch`

(Originally posted answer):

```
Catch[Scan[If[f[#][[2]], Throw[f@#]] &, dataPairs]]

(* {e, True}  *)
```

The only 'side effect' is to return the list obtained by calling `f` on the subexpression where the last part of that function call is `True`

**Using** `Do/Return`

Substituting [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html)
for [`Scan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html):

```
Do[If[Last@f@dataPairs[[i]],Return[f@dataPairs[[i]]]], {i,Length@dataPairs}]

(* {e, True} *)
```

**Map/Scan**

```
mat={
{{a, 0.0027}, {b, 0.0027}, {c, 0.0027}, {d, 0.002}, {e, 0}, {f, 0.0027}, {g, 0.002}},
{{a, 0}, {b, 0.0027}, {c, 0.0027}, {d, 0.002}, {e, 0}, {f, 0.0027}, {g, 0.002}},
{{a, 0.0027}, {b, 0.0027}, {c, 0.0027}, {d, 0.002}, {e, 002}, {f, 0.0027}, {g, 0.000}}
}

Scan[If[f[#][[2]], Return[f@#]]&,#]&/@mat

(* {{e, True}, {a, True}, {g, True}} *)
```

Comment: Testing this now on my full application and code (well the first couple of thousand).  It seems to work, but I can't say I understand how it works.  Can I trouble you for an explanation?  Does it have something to do with `f[#][[2]]`?

Comment: `Catch[Scan[If[f[#][[2]], Throw[f[#]]] &, dataPairs]]` actually gives me the precise output that I need: `{e, True}`.  Still, very interesting solution!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Your selection function can be simplified. I'm not sure what output you actually want, so I'll show two options.

```
(* the parameters as you've given them *)
yld = 0.0742;
pVal = 10000;
pVal2 = 10000;
dataPairs = {{a, 0.0027}, {b, 0.0027}, {c, 0.0027}, {d, 0.002}, {e, 0}, {f, 0.0027}, {g, 0.002}};

(* a selector function *)
fAlt[data_] := pVal2 (yld*Last@data + 1) <= pVal
```

The following will get you the first pair that satisfies fAlt:

```
SelectFirst[dataPairs, fAlt]
```

The following will get you the list up until (and excluding) the first pair that satisfies fAlt:

```
TakeWhile[dataPairs, Not@*fAlt]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  Your `SelectFirst[dataPairs, fAlt]` most suited to my needs.  I intend to put it into a speed match with @user1066's answer ;-).