# Is there a bug in the Part function of Mathematica 10?

Tags: list-manipulation, documentation

I am using Mathematica 10 now.

I typed code below

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}}[[;; , 1]][[1]]
```

and this gives result

```
1
```

But code

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}}[[;; , 1, 1]]
```

gives error

> Part::partd: Part specification
>   {{1,2},{2,4},{3,6},{4,8}}[[1;;All,1,1]] is longer than depth of
>   object. >>

But according to help doc

> expr[[i,j,...]]] or Part[expr,i,j,...]] is equivalent to
>   expr[[i]][[j]]...

What is wrong?!! I remember I always coded it like this in Mathematica 9, no error occurs. Is it a bug??

Comment: `Span` threads over the defined elements, which then do not have sufficient depth for the last part specification. E.g.  `{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}}[[1, 1, 1]]` returns the same error (on probably any version). Note: I removed the `bugs` tag, which is for confirmed bugs only.

Comment: Also from the docs: "Successive part extraction is not always equivalent to direct part extraction". Perhaps it is better to read the piece you quote from the docs with the implicit proviso: "If  `expr[[i,j,...]]` is a valid expression, it is equivalent to ..."?

Comment: Oh, and 9.01 throws the same error.

Comment: @kguler Oh, such a delicate definition. Probably you are right.

Comment: @MichaelE2 hmm... I am still waiting for someone in the know to expose the innards of `Part`+`Span` evaluation. That might actually be quite useful!

Comment: @YvesKlett OK, I've answered.  I just thought from your comment that you could and I didn't want to poach.  I've been tricked by this before, so I agree that answering is good.

Comment: @MichaelE2 you are most welcome - thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 8):

**General explanation**

First, in general, a valid `expr[[i1, i2,..., in]]]` requires `expr` to have at least `n` levels, and the result will have `n` fewer levels.

The OP's example list `{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}}` has two.  The code

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}}[[;; , 1, 1]]
```

needs at least three levels.  Hence the error.

Next, in the sentence of the documentation for [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html),

> expr[[i,j,...]] or Part[expr,i,j,...]] is equivalent to expr[[i]][[j]]...

the `i`, `j`, ... are to be integers, or so I used to think.  However, as [@kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kguler) said in a comment, the equivalence holds if `expr[[i, j,...]]` is valid.

If instead of an integer, a [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html) or a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/List.html) (or `All`) is used, the result will be a (possibly nested) list.  Each `Span` and `List` adds a level to the depth of the result one would have had if every part had been a simple integer.  This allows for further extraction of parts as in the OP's first example.

**OP's first example**

We can break down the OP's example as follows.  The expression

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}}[[;; , 1]][[1]]
```

is equivalent to the last result of

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}}[[;; , 1]]
%[[1]]
(*
  {1, 2, 3, 4}
  1
*)
```

The first expression has a `Span` and evaluates to a list of parts, the first part of each expression at level 2.  Adding a `[[1]]` extracts the first part of this list.

It may be a little easier to see what's going on in an example that gives no errors:

```
foo = ArrayReshape[Range@8, {4, 2, 1}]
foo[[;; , 1, 1]]
foo[[;; , 1]][[1]]
(*
  {{{1}, {2}}, {{3}, {4}}, {{5}, {6}}, {{7}, {8}}}
  {1, 3, 5, 7}
  {1}
*)
```

The last output is a list because `{1}` is the first part of

```
foo[[;; , 1]]
(*
  {{1}, {3}, {5}, {7}}
*)
```

Comment: To the down-voter: Is there an error or some other issue?

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, I never downvote correct answers. I'm just trying to detect an individual who downvoted mine  a few minutes ago. Threre are very few suspicious...

Comment: @Artes All in all, it's been a considerate community, whose criticism has been carried out in a reasonably honest way.  Let's hope it stays that way.

Comment: It could be an interesting question to write an application in _Mathematica_ finding who downvoted an answer. Comparing reputation points in collective registry of users (it subtracts points when one downvotes) with individual profiles (where points from downvoting are not registered) we can find downvoters. By using my pedestrian approach I could find only 3 suspected, but improving it with another characteristics we could approach up to $90$% certainity on average:).

Answer (score 3):

When using `[[All, 1, 1]]` you are attempting to extract the first element of the first element of all parts of the expression.  Note what happens when you specify `0` instead of `1`, which *is* a valid "part" of `1` etc.:

```
{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}}[[All, 1, 0]]
```

> ```
> {Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer}
> ```

Part `0` is the head of an expression. See:  [Is there a summary of answers Head[] can give?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22449/121)

Comment: Wow, deep understanding! Thanks, Mr. Wizard