# Surprising behavior of Part[ ]

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

Look at this list

```
list={1,2,3,4}
```

Obiously

```
list[[1, 2]]
```

throws the error:

During evaluation of Part::partd: Part specification {1,2,3,4}[[1,2]] is longer than depth of object.

However:

```
list[[1,All]]
```

yields  (Mathematica 12 on Windows)

```
Integer[]
```

which does not make much sense to me. Moreover, weird constructs like
`list[[All,All,All,All,All]]`  do not throw an error.

Can this (at least to me) strange behaviour of the basic command  `Part[]`
be explained?  (Needless to say, that this is just a simple demonstration of the effect, but it occured during execution a larger program with strange consequences.)

EDIT:
I just realized that [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58617/is-there-a-bug-in-the-part-function-of-mathematica-10) is closely related to mine and adds some more aspects to it.

Comment: Indeed a bit irregular, but not completely derstandable (=ununderstandable ;) - cf `list[[1, 0]]`.

Comment: There are similar oddities with `Span`: Consider `e[[1 ;; -1]]` and `e[[2 ;; -1]]`, with `e` being `1`, `f[]`, and `f[1]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compare:

```
17[[All]]
(* Integer[] *)
```

The evaluation of `expr[[All]]` should result in `h[p1, p2,...]` where `h` is `Head[expr]` and `p1, p2,...` is a possibly empty list (not `List`) of all the parts of `expr`.  An `Integer` has no parts (because it is [atomic](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AtomicElementsOfExpressions.html)), but its head is `Integer`.  Hence we get `Integer` with an empty argument list.

Comment: Well, I do accept that 17[[All]] returns an Integer[ ], but I am surprised that it does not throw a message, as e.g. xxx[[All]] returns Symbol[ ] but does throw a message. 1.2[[All]] does not as well.

Comment: @MichaelWeyrauch `xxx[[All]]` does not throw a message. It is `Symbol[]` that throws the message. It's not `Part`.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the following example:

We have a list of 3-tuples:

```
list = {{1,2,3}, {5,4,3}, {9,7,5}, {0,3,8}}
```

Take the first element of each sublist.

```
list[[All, 1]]
(* {1,5,9,0} *)
```

If the list had 4 elements, the result will have 4 elements too. In general, if the list has $n$ elements, the result should also have $n$ elements. But what if the list is empty, i.e. $n=0$?  It would be reasonable to get a result with 0 elements, of course. But for that to work, `Part` needs to be a bit flexible, after all, we can't take the 1st element of nothing ... or can we?

```
list = {}

list[[All, 1]]
(* {} *)
```

Well, it works. And it is extremely useful because I do not need to have extra code for these special cases.

This explains why it is okay to add more indexes to `Part` than the number of levels that the expression has. This is why you can have 10 `All`s in there. But you could also have `list[[All, All, 1, 1]]`, not just `list[[All, All, All, All]]`

---

As for why `1[[All]]` is `Integer[]`, [Michael has already explained it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197298/12).  My answer is only for explaining why you can have many `All`s in there.

Comment: I just wrote code that relies on this yesterday. I find it very useful.