# Why can't a string be formed by head String?

Tags: core-language, expression-construction

Since [everything is an expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html) in *Mathematica*, why must a string object be formed by  `"abc"` but not by a `String[abc]` expression?

You can look at a string's head by:

```
Head["abc"]
```

> ```
> String
> ```

But you can not produce the same string by `String`

```
String[abc]
```

which, from my point of view, seems inconsistent with the principle that *Everything Is an Expression*.

However, I noticed that the basic `Symbol` object, on the other hand, *can* be formed by something like `Symbol["a"]`.

The same question goes for four number objects (`Integer`, `Real`, `Rational`, and `Complex`). You can't say an integer 1 by something like `Integer[1]`, can you?

---

Edit:`Rational` and `Complex` *can* be produced by their respective heads. So The question is valid only for `String` and two number objects, i.e. `Integer` and `Real`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`String` and `Integer` are what I termed "implicit heads" while writing:

- [Is there a summary of answers Head[] can give?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22449/is-there-a-summary-of-answers-head-can-give/22450#22450)

Rather than being part of the standard expression itself, at least as I understand it, these implicit heads instead serve the purpose of providing a "type" for pattern matching.  (With a pattern `_String`, `_Integer`, etc.)  The atomic expressions themselves are stored in a low-level format and handled transparently behind the scenes.

Of the heads you list `Rational` and `Complex` are exceptions as these are a kind of hybrid head: you *can* use them to enter data:

```
{Complex[1, 2], Rational[5, 8]}
```

> ```
> {1 + 2 I, 5/8}
> ```

Critically you can also match patterns *within* these heads:

```
{1 + 2 I, 5/8} /. {Complex[a_, b_] :> foo[a, b], Rational[n_, m_] :> bar[n, m]}
```

> ```
> {foo[1, 2], bar[5, 8]}
> ```

Nevertheless these expressions are considered "atomic" and they cannot be manipulated other ways that apply to standard expressions:

```
AtomQ /@ {1 + 2 I, 5/8}
foo @@@ {1 + 2 I, 5/8}
```

> ```
> {True, True}
>
> {1 + 2 I, 5/8}
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry for misleadingly including the `Rational` and `Complex`. I just got a bit "unconscious" for forgetting that they are not the same case. I have excluded them from my descriptive details to avoid possible misguidance.

Comment: @Naitree I found them an interesting aspect of the question and took a large portion of my answer to address them.  Unless you feel that my answer is inadequate (which the Accept indicates against) I prefer that you restore your question to its original form.

Comment: After reading your answer, I thought it might be misleading for _other_ readers to include a stated fact which is actually false. That's the reason I removed them. I will now re-include them for consistency and add additional comments for avoiding misguidance for _other_ readers.