# Get expression type?

Tags: variable, data-types

Is there a built in function that distinguishes between different kinds of variables?
I mean something like:

```
VariableType[ 123 ]
```

> Number

```
VariableType[ f[x] ]
```

> Function

```
VariableType[ x ]
```

> Variable

```
A={{a,b},{c,d}};
VariableType[ A ]
```

> List

Etc.? Please let me know how this function is actually called. Or maybe one can implement it?

Comment: What you want is `Head`, although it cannot distinguish functions, because they are usual symbols in Mathematica. Try `Head[{a,b,c}]` or `Head[1]` or `Head[1.0]`

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, you may also be interested in `Blank` with a `Head` specified, like `_Integer`, `_String`, `_a`

Comment: See also: [(22449)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22449/121), [(59671)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59671/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's a duplicate of the first link you provided. On the other hand, to find this link, you already have to know `Head` - of which the OP apparently wasn't aware of. To close or not to close ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**A few examples**

```
fun[x_] := x^2

sphere = Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.01]}, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 30];

str =
  {"1", "Pi", "{f}", "f", "f[x]", "f+f", "Inactivate[f+f,Plus]",
   "Hold[1+2+3]", "{1,{2,{3}}}", "fun[2]", "fun[x]", "Cos[Exp[x]]",
   "Red", "sphere", "DateObject[{2014,10}]"};

table =
  With[{exp = ToExpression /@ str},
   Prepend[
    Transpose[{
      str,
      exp,
      Head /@ exp,
      LeafCount /@ exp,
      Map[TreeForm[#,
         AspectRatio -> 1,
         ImageSize -> 40,
         PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium],
         VertexRenderingFunction -> Function[{p}, Point[p]]] &,
       exp]}],
    Style[#, Bold, 16] & /@ {"Input", "Output", "Head", "Leaves", "Graph"}]];

Framed[
 Grid[table,
  Alignment -> Left,
  Dividers -> All,
  Spacings -> {{2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, 2},
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
  Background -> {None, {{Hue[.6, .15, .9], GrayLevel[.9]}}},
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, White]],
 FrameMargins -> 0.5,
 FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.7]]
```

[image]

```
Grid[
 Partition[
  Map[TreeForm[#,
     AspectRatio -> 1,
     ImageSize -> 200,
     EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Black, Arrow[#, 0.2]} &)] &,
   {1, {f}, f + f,
    fun[x], Red, DateObject[{2014, 10}],
    Hold[1 + 2 + 3], {1, {2, {3}}}, sphere}],
  3],
 Background -> GrayLevel@0.95,
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

See the documentation for [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Head.html) and read the tutorials linked therein:

- [Everything Is an Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html)
- [Specifying Types of Expression in Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecifyingTypesOfExpressionInPatterns.html)

**Just for fun**

```
a[b] + c[d] /. head_[_] :> head
```

> a + c

```
a[b] + c[d] /. head_[_, _] :> head
```

> Plus

Comment: Great answer, but very complex... any possibility to have a brief explanation of the results? is the sort answer the function Head[]? Thanks!!

Comment: Where is the relevant expression?