# Get the sum with cases

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

I have the following list:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {2}, {3, 4, 1}, {5, 4}, {3, 3}, {a, b, c}, {e, f}, {g}, {}, {Sin[a], Cos[b]}};
```

I should use `Cases` function `Cases[list, pattern -> expr]` with patterns or rules to get the following sums:

(a) the sum of all subexpressions with the length 2. Result:

> {3,9,6,e+f,Cos[b]+Sin[a]}

(b) as in (a), but only for Integer numbers. Result:

> {3,9,6}

(c) the sum of all subexpressions with the length >= 2. Result:

> {3,8,9,6,a+b+c,e+f,Cos[b]+Sin[a]}

(d) the sum of ALL subexpressions. Result:

> {3,2,8,9,6,a+b+c,e+f,g,0,Cos[b]+Sin[a]}

PS. It's not a homework. I learn for a test. This is an exercise I don't understand. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Cases[list, _?(Total[[Length[#] == 2], Infinity] &)] but it doesn't work

Comment: You were almost there, you just mashed up replacements and tests together. `Cases[list, _?(Length[#] == 2 &)]` picks out the right elements, `Total/@Cases[list, _?(Length[#] == 2 &)]` gets their sums.

Answer (score 3):

```
Cases[list, x : {_, _} :> Plus @@ x]
(* {3, 9, 6, e + f, Cos[b] + Sin[a]} *)

Cases[list, x : {_Integer, _Integer} :> Plus @@ x]
(* {3, 9, 6} *)

Cases[list, x : {_, __} :> Plus @@ x]
(* {3, 8, 9, 6, a + b + c, e + f, Cos[b] + Sin[a]}*)

Cases[list, x : {___} :> Plus @@ x]
(* {3, 2, 8, 9, 6, a + b + c, e + f, g, 0, Cos[b] + Sin[a]} *)
```

Or

```
patterns = {{_, _}, {_Integer, _Integer}, {_, __}, {___}};

Cases[list, x : # :> Plus @@ x] & /@ patterns
(* {{3, 9, 6, e + f, Cos[b] + Sin[a]}, 
    {3, 9, 6}, 
    {3, 8, 9, 6, a + b + c, e + f, Cos[b] + Sin[a]}, 
    {3, 2, 8, 9, 6, a + b + c, e + f, g, 0, Cos[b] + Sin[a]}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) can be very helpful.  Also you can use `+x` as a shorthand for `Plus[x]`, and `x` can be bound to a sequence. `_Integer` is the pattern for an expression with head `Integer`.  (For my description of heads please see [Is there a summary of answers Head[] can give?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22449/121) and [Why can't a string be formed by head String?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59671/121)) Therefore for (b):

```
Cases[list, {x : Repeated[_Integer, {2}]} :> +x]
```

> ```
> {3, 9, 6}
> ```

To sum all sublists I would either use [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) or [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr.html) across the `list`:

```
Total[list, {2}]

Tr /@ list
```

> ```
> {3, 2, 8, 9, 6, a + b + c, e + f, g, 0, Cos[b] + Sin[a]}   (* output from either *)
> ```