# Evaluation speed of apparently equivalent functions

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Consider the following expressions:

```
f[x_Integer] := x, 
f[x_] := x /; x ∈ Integers, 
f[x_?IntegerQ] := x
```

All of the expressions above (and probably others which I don't know) seem to do the exact same thing.

However, what I'm curious to know is: are they really equivalent, or are there circumstances where one is preferable (faster, slower?) over the other?

Comment: Do a `Trace` on each, s/b/ illuminating...

Comment: closely related: [1835](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1835/5478)

Comment: I would be surprised if `[x_Integer]  :=  x` were not the fastest of the examples you give, for the simple reason that it requires the least effort to determine whether the actual argument passed matches the argument pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 10.1 timings are pretty much as I expected:

```
f1[x_Integer] := x;
f2[x_] := x /; x ∈ Integers;
f3[x_?IntegerQ] := x;

First @ Timing @ Do[#[i], {i, 1*^6}] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}
```

> ```
> {0.374402, 1.06081, 0.499203}
> ```

As m_goldberg commented `_Integer` *should* be fastest as unlike the others it does not require evaluation; it directly matches the (["implicit"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22450/121)) head of the argument.  This difference becomes more important with functions that hold their arguments.

```
SetAttributes[{f1, f2, f3}, HoldAll]

foo := Print["pop!"]
```

With `f1` the `Print` does not evaluate:

```
f1[foo];  (* nothing printed *)
```

With `f2` and `f2` it does:

```
f2[foo];
f3[foo];
```

> pop!
>
> pop!

That also results in this evaluation behavior:

```
z = 1;

f1[z]
f2[z]
f3[z]
```

> ```
> f1[z]
>
> 1
>
> 1
> ```

`f1` matches only an explicit integer and `z` is not but since `f2` and `f3` evaluate their arguments in the course of pattern matching the assigned value of `z` is used, matched, and returned.

Comment: I like the way you explain things. If one wants to understand MMA deeply then he just need to follow your answers:).

Comment: @Algohi Thanks!  Several people have suggested I write a book on *Mathematica*.  Recently I am beginning to consider that seriously.  Feedback on what is clear or useful in my answers and what is confusing, needless, or simply wrong is appreciated.

Comment: That would be great help from you to the community. I strongly support the idea you write a book and I will be waiting to read it.

Answer (score 1):

```
f1[x_Integer] = x;
f2[x_] = x /; x \[Element] Integers; 
f3[x_?IntegerQ] = x;

Timing[f1 /@ Range[10^6];]
```

> {0.424561, Null}

```
Timing[f2 /@ Range[10^6];]
```

> {0.69525, Null}

```
Timing[f3 /@ Range[10^6];]
```

> {0.630597, Null}