# Unexpected behavior with Map

Tags: map

Using Map, one can apply a function f to the elements of a list:

```
Clear[f];
Map[f,Range[10]]
(*{f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6], f[7], f[8], f[9], f[10]}*)
```

But the command does not seem to work if any modification is applied to f. For example:

```
Map[-f,Range[10]]
(*{(-f)[1], (-f)[2], (-f)[3], (-f)[4], (-f)[5], (-f)[6], (-f)[7], (-f)[8], (-f)[9], (-f)[10]}*)
```

This is illustrated with an example:

```
f[x_]=2x;
Map[f, Range[10]]
(*{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}*)
Map[-f, Range[10]]
(*{(-f)[1], (-f)[2], (-f)[3], (-f)[4], (-f)[5], (-f)[6], (-f)[7], (-f)[
8], (-f)[9], (-f)[10]}*)
```

Is there a way to evaluate this expression to the desired result ?

Comment: Take a look at `FullForm@(-f)` this is what you are mapping with while you should use `Minus @* f` or something.

Comment: You cannot do operations on the head in the way you desire. You cannot define -x = 4. Any reason you want it done this way ? The natural way would be to have Map[f, -Range[10]] instead of Map[-f, Range[10]]

Comment: @Lotus Yes, specifically, I was looking to map the sum of two functions f1 and f2 I have previously defined, as in Map[f1+f2, list]. Instead, I ham ressorting to applying them separately, Map[f1, list]+Map[f2,list], which is less compact.

Comment: Maybe `Map[(f@# + g@#) &, Range[10]]` where g[x_] = 3 x; (or, `Range[10] // Map[(f@# + g@#) &, #] &`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As noted in comments, the standard ways to evaluate such result is to use `Composition` or pure function.

Using `Composition`:

```
Map[Minus@*f, Range[10]]
```

> {-f[1], -f[2], -f[3], -f[4], -f[5], -f[6], -f[7], -f[8], -f[9], -f[10]}

Using pure function:

```
Map[(-f[#1])&, Range[10]]
```

> {-f[1], -f[2], -f[3], -f[4], -f[5], -f[6], -f[7], -f[8], -f[9], -f[10]}

Comment: or `-Map[f, Range[10]]`

Answer (score 9):

Heads in *Mathematica* can be [any expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22449/121). `Map` is doing just as it is instructed.

Perhaps you would like an abstraction along these lines:

```
deepMap[template_, target_, lev_: {1}] :=
  Map[
    Replace[template &, s_Symbol :> s[#], {-1}, Heads -> False],
    target,
    lev
  ]
```

Now:

```
deepMap[-f, {1, 2, 3}]

deepMap[Sin + Cos, {a, b, c}]

deepMap[j^2/k - m, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {-f[1], -f[2], -f[3]}
>
> {Cos[a] + Sin[a], Cos[b] + Sin[b], Cos[c] + Sin[c]}
>
> {{j[1]^2/k[1] - m[1], j[2]^2/k[2] - m[2]}, {j[3]^2/k[3] - m[3], j[4]^2/k[4] - m[4]}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

In:

```
Clear[f]
f[s_][x_] := 2 x s
Map[f[1], Range[10]]
Map[f[-1], Range[10]]
```

Out:

> {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}
>
> {-2, -4, -6, -8, -10, -12, -14, -16, -18, -20}