# How to extract a variable names (not values) from a list of transformation rules?

Tags: evaluation, assignment, hold

I am trying to extract variable names from a list of transformation rules `mapping = {var1 -> 'val1', var2 -> 'val2' }`. Variables `var1` and `var2` are already defined in my notebook:

`var1 = 'init-val1';
var2 = 'init-val2';`

When I try to evaluate `Extract[mapping, {1,1}, HoldForm]`, I get `'init-val1'`, instead of `var1`.

What am I doing wrong? Why is `var1` getting evaluated despite the explicit `HoldForm` wrapper? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Check your `mapping`... the evaluation has already happened when you assigned it to `mapping`, so the `HoldForm` is useless. If you explained the intent behind what you're trying to do, then perhaps we can provide a solution that doesn't involve  playing catch up with the evaluator.

Comment: @rm-rf, when I evaluate `Definition[mapping]` I still get `{var1 -> 'val1', var2 -> 'val2' }`. So in the definition I don't get the substitution of `var1` for `'init-val1'`.

Comment: `var1 = "init-val1";
mapping = {var1 -> "val1", var2 -> "val2"};
Definition[mapping]` gives `mapping = {"init-val1" -> "val1", var2 -> "val2"}`as expected

Comment: @belisarius If you do it the other way round, `Definition` will give you what the OP said. This is different, because in your case, clearing `var1` has no effect on `mapping` but it does in this one.

Comment: @rm-rf So what does _"Variables var1 and var2 are already defined in my notebook:"_ mean?

Comment: @belisarius The question isn't clear... it isn't apparent whether `mapping` is defined before or after. Your interpretation is certainly valid given what OP wrote, but if that were the case, then they won't get the output above. That's why I asked OP to explain what they want to do.

Comment: @rm-rf Ok, let's wait for some clarification

Comment: @belisarius, @rm-rf, thanks for the explanation. As soon as `var1` and `var2` were defined, `mappings` evaluation used their values instead of name. I had to redefine `mappings` using `HoldForm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem is the reason I sought and found a solution to:

- [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/121)

Here is an example of how the `step` function defined in my answer there is used:

```
var1 = "init-val1"; var2 = "init-val2";

mapping := {var1 -> "val1", var2 -> "val2"}   (* note use of := *)

step[mapping][[{1}, 1, 1]]

% // InputForm
```

> ```
> var1
>
> HoldForm[var1]
> ```

The return is `var1` wrapped in `HoldForm`.  This is because `step[mapping]` returns:

```
HoldForm[{var1 -> "val1", var2 -> "val2"}]
```

And the use of `{1}` in `Part` preserves the head; see:

- [Head and everything except Head?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/121)

Recommended reading:

- [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121)