# Different results with DateRange and LeapYearsQ in Mathematica 9 and 10

Tags: date-and-time

With Mathematica 9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013) one could use

```
DateRange[{2000}, {2010}, "Year"]
```

to achive

```
{{2000}, {2001}, {2002}, {2003}, {2004}, {2005}, {2006}, {2007}, {2008}, {2009}, {2010}}
```

or

```
leapyears = Select[DateRange[{2000}, {2020}, "Year"], LeapYearQ[#] &]
```

with the result

```
{{2000}, {2004}, {2008}, {2012}, {2016}, {2020}}
```

With Mathematica 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)

```
DateRange[{2000}, {2010}, "Year"]
```

one will get

```
{{2000, 1, 1}, {2001, 1, 1}, {2002, 1, 1}, {2003, 1, 1}, {2004, 1, 
  1}, {2005, 1, 1}, {2006, 1, 1}, {2007, 1, 1}, {2008, 1, 1}, {2009, 
  1, 1}, {2010, 1, 1}}
```

`leapyears = Select[DateRange[{2000}, {2020}, "Year"], LeapYearQ[#] &]`

```
{{2000, 1, 1}, {2004, 1, 1}, {2008, 1, 1}, {2012, 1, 1}, {2016, 1, 
  1}, {2020, 1, 1}}
```

The Function `DateObject` does not clear a bean to me

```
DateRange[DateObject[{2000}], DateObject[{2012}], "Year"]
```

[image]

So, how can i get rid of the additional `month, day` information on V10, i.e. using `leapyears` and `DateObject` returning `Year` only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use:

```
DateRange[{2000}, {2010}, "Year"][[All, {1}]]
```

> ```
> {{2000}, {2001}, {2002}, {2003}, {2004}, {2005}, {2006}, {2007}, {2008}, {2009}, {2010}}
> ```

```
% ~Select~ LeapYearQ
```

> ```
> {{2000}, {2004}, {2008}}
> ```

Note the `{1}` in the `Part` parameters; see [Head and everything except Head?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/121)

Comment: Thanks for the link & hint to use the marble in my head +1.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid you now have to extract that information by yourself. This performs the same function as eldo's code, but instead of using `Map` twice I use `Composition`. It is also showcasing the new *Mathematica* 10 syntax.

```
Map[List@*First]@*Select[LeapYearQ]@DateRange[{2000}, {2020}, "Year"]
```

> `{{2000}, {2004}, {2008}, {2012}, {2016}, {2020}}`

In order to extract the year from a `DateObject` you can use `DateValue`:

```
Map[List@*(DateValue[#, "Year"] &)]@Select[LeapYearQ]@DateRange[DateObject[{2000}], DateObject[{2012}], "Year"]
```

> `{{2000}, {2004}, {2008}, {2012}, {2016}, {2020}}`

Comment: The first part of your answer is nothing but a V10 rephrasing of my earlier answer

Comment: @eldo No, it's faster. You iterate over the list twice because you use `Map` twice, but I use `Composition` so I only map over it once. You could do that in V9 as well. Anyway, I think the new V10 syntax should get some extra attention now in the beginning, and I was adding something else with my answer, it wasn't just consisting of that.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, and the second part of your answer is +1 anyway.

Comment: @Pickett, Yep ... +1.

Answer (score 2):

As to your first question:

```
List /@ First /@ Select[DateRange[{2000}, {2020}, "Year"], LeapYearQ]
```

> ```
> {{2000}, {2004}, {2008}, {2012}, {2016}, {2020}}
> ```