# Renaming a large number of elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a lot of elements of this kind: `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]`, ... I would like to rename each of them as follows: `a[1]=a1`, `a[2]=a2`, `a[3]=a3`, ...

The elements `a1`, `a2`, `a3`,... differ from each other only by the string type number, so it is not very clear how to apply `Table` to them, for example.

Is it possible to do this kind of renaming in some loop?

Comment: try `Symbol[SymbolName[#[[0]]] <> ToString[#[[1]]]] & /@ yourlist` or `ReplaceAll[f_[i_Integer] :> Symbol@StringJoin[ToString /@ {f, i}]]@lyourlist`

Comment: When you say "a lot", do you mean "a lot of `a`, `b`, `c`..." (so, you may have only three `a`s: `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]`, but you also have three each for 20 different symbols) or do you mean you have `a[1]`...`a[500]` and only a few different head-symbols?

Comment: @kglr, thanks a lot!

Comment: A more general duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94294/what-are-the-requirements-for-a-well-behaved-indexed-variable-subscript-toexpr -- Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59242/issue-with-very-large-lists-in-mathematica/59293#59293, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51765/how-to-create-a-writable-and-clearable-symbol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this works in your context, but if you have no reason to distinguish the "atomic" symbol from the bracket expression, you could just create down values:

```
a[id_] := Symbol["a" <> ToString[id]]
```

Once you do that, you won't have to do any replacing, the evaluation engine will apply the transformation for you wherever the bracket expressions occur.

```
a[5]
(* a5 *)

(* but later ...*)
a5 = 17;
a[5]
(* 17 *)

(* or similarly ...*)
a[5] = 17;
a5
(* 17 *)

(* and also ... *)
Array[a, 5]
(* {a1, a2, a3, a4, 17} *)

(* and also ...*)
Table[a[i], {i, 1, 5}]
(* {a1, a2, a3, a4, 17} *)
```

Comment: It may be relevant to read [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397) by *Leonid Shifrin* arguing that *"Using strings and subsequently ToString - ToExpression just to generate variable names is pretty much unacceptable, or at the very least should be the last thing you try"* .