# How to extract a contiguous s_1 x s_2 x ... x s_d subarray from an n_1 x n_2 x ... x n_d array, where the dimension d is a variable

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a multidimensional array, such as the 3-dimensional 2 x 2 x 3 array

```
{
 {{a,b,c},{d,e,f}},
 {{g,h,i},{j,k,l}}
}
```

How can I extract an arbitrary 3-dimensional contiguous subarray, such as slice 1, rows 1-2 and columns 2-3, which is

```
{
 {{b,c},{e,f}}
}
```

This is not too hard, using `Part`, `Take`, `Extract`, etc.

But how can I do it for an array of arbitrary dimension `d`? Must I use recursion somehow ?

Comment: "This is not too hard, using Part, Take, Extract, etc." What have you tried? Can you share some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy using [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), which allows specifications of arbitrary depth, and [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html):

```
m = {{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}, {{g, h, i}, {j, k, l}}}

m[[1, 1 ;; 2, 2 ;; 3]]
```

> ```
> {{b, c}, {e, f}}
> ```

If you want full bracket depth in the output make any single part specification a `List`:

```
m[[{1}, 1 ;; 2, 2 ;; 3]]
```

> ```
> {{{b, c}, {e, f}}}
> ```

See: [Head and everything except Head?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/121)

---

This is an attempt to address an example provided in the comments.  As I understand it your example can be reduced to:

```
x = Fold[Partition, Range@12, {3, 2}]

MapThread[# ;; # + #2 - 1 &, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}]

x[[##]] & @@ %
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}}
>
> {1 ;; 2, 2 ;; 2, 2 ;; 3}
>
> {{{5, 6}}, {{11, 12}}}
> ```

There is nothing about this that is restricted to three dimensions as far as I can see.
Here is the same code again with a larger tensor:

```
x = Fold[Partition, Range@72, {3, 4, 2}];

x[[##]] & @@ MapThread[# ;; # + #2 - 1 &, {{1, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 2}}]
```

> ```
> {{{{14, 15}, {17, 18}}}, {{{38, 39}, {41, 42}}}}
> ```

Other ways to write the same operation:

```
a = {1, 2, 1, 2};
b = {2, 1, 2, 2};

Inner[# ;; # + #2 - 1 &, a, b, x[[##]] &]
```

> ```
> {{{{14, 15}, {17, 18}}}, {{{38, 39}, {41, 42}}}}
> ```

```
Take[x, ##] & @@ ({a, a + b - 1}\[Transpose])
```

> ```
> {{{{14, 15}, {17, 18}}}, {{{38, 39}, {41, 42}}}}
> ```

```
Take[Drop[x, ##] & @@ (a - 1), ##] & @@ b
```

> ```
> {{{{14, 15}, {17, 18}}}, {{{38, 39}, {41, 42}}}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mr.Wizard and blochwave. Here is an example of what I mean: arraydims = {2, 2, 3}; cases = Tuples[{0, 1}, arraydims]; badsubarraydims = {2, 1, 2};badsubarrayoffset={1, 2, 2};cases[[792]]

Comment: Now %[[badsubarrayoffset[[1]];;badsubarrayoffset[[1]]+badsubarraydims[[1]]-1, badsubarrayoffset[[2]];;badsubarrayoffset[[2]]+badsubarraydims[[2]]-1, badsubarrayoffset[[3]];;badsubarrayoffset[[3]]+badsubarraydims[[3]]-1]

Comment: will extract a contiguous 2x1x2 array from the 2x2x3 array, but how can I remove the inherent 3-dimensional-ness from the extraction command ? I would like to pass that command the parameter Length[arraydims], which in this case would be 3, so that the code works equally well in dimension 1,2,3,4,etc.

Comment: @Simon I am not sure I understand your problem but I shall attempt to provide something helpful anyway.  I shall update this answer soon.

Comment: Dear @Mr.Wizard, thank you very much indeed ! I think that is exactly what I want. I see that your code is dimension-free: You could substitute arbitrary lists of arbitrary length in place of the particular lists you have used, provided the dimensions agreed etc. Thank you so much again !

Comment: @Simon If you find this answer fully satisfactory please consider Accepting it.  See: [(5234)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/121)