# Select elements from list with given head

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I would like to select elements from list by specifying their head. E.g.

```
SelectWithHead[{1,2,3.5,x}, Symbol] = {x}
SelectWithHead[{1,2,3.5,x}, Real] = {3.5}
```

What is the simpliest way for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Select[{1,2,3,5,x}, Head[#] === Symbol&]` would work, but I would recommend using cases instead:

```
Cases[{1,2,3,5,x}, _Symbol]
```

> {x}

---

One advantage of using the pattern `_head` is that it will not cause unwanted evaluation.  To keep `Head[#] === Symbol &` from evaluating its argument would require rewriting it as something like `Function[x, Head @ Unevaluated @ x == Symbol, HoldAll]`, whereas the `Cases` form allows this directly:

```
Cases[Hold[1 + 2, 3*4, 5^6], _Plus]
```

> ```
> {3}
> ```

Although evaluation took place after the match `_Plus` successfully matched (only) the held expression of the form `Plus[1, 2]`.  To return that expression also unevaluated we can use a delayed rule:

```
Cases[Hold[1 + 2, 3*4, 5^6], x_Plus :> Defer[x]]
```

> {1 + 2}

(I chose [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) for this example but [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) or [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) may be used instead as required.)

Comment: Ah, Cases, that wat was I looking for. Will accept ASAP

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @uranix You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Although most of the time I would prefer `Cases` there is an alternative worth mentioning: [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html).

```
expr = Hold[1 + 2, 3*4, 5^6];

Pick[expr, expr[[All, 0]], Plus]
```

> ```
> Hold[1 + 2]
> ```

[`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) zero is used to extract the head and [`All`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/All.html) represents a sequence therefore the original head `Hold` is retained. (See: [Head and everything except Head?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/121)) `Pick` then finds the position(s) of literal `Plus` in `Hold[Plus, Times, Power]` and extracts the element at that position from the original `Hold[1 + 2, 3*4, 5^6]`, again preserving the original head.