# Accesing keys based on position in an association

Tags: associations

I would like to have the following simple function `GetKey[]` on a very large association.

```
(* The actual Association is very large, this is just small example *) 
assoc = <|{1,1} -> 2, {1,2} -> 3, {2,1}->4, {2,2}->5|>;
GetKey[assoc, 1]
GetKey[assoc, 4]

(* output *) 
{1,1}
{2,2}
```

That is, I want to access keys based on their position in the association. Any way this can be done efficiently for a large association? I know one can use the `Keys[assoc][[position]]` function but this is too slow for a large association.

**EDIT:** Based on the comments below I am giving you the timing information for the function I know that does the job.

```
a = 1024*1024;
keys = Table[i, {i, a}];
values = RandomReal[{0, 1000000}, {a}];
assoc = Association[MapThread[Rule, {keys, values}]];
AbsoluteTiming[k = Keys[assoc][[10000]];]

(* output *)
{0.548738, Null}
```

This is too slow for say a hundred thousand accesses.

Comment: which version of Mathematica are you using? I do not have `GetKey` in my mathematica and I am using `11.1.1` if this is meant to be your own function, then it is better to use `LowerFirstCaseLetter` to reduce confusion from someone thinking it is build-in function.

Comment: I am sorry I should have pointed that out, GetKey is the function I want. It's not built in.

Comment: I do not think `position` on association has any sematics to it. This is like  a hash table. So asking for `position` does not seem to be well defined here. But I am not an expert with association. I do not use it. You can ask about a `position` of an entry for a list for example.

Comment: I understand your point. But I am using association in two ways. One as a lookup table for indices of the form $\{i, j\}$ and the other a way to index into these indices based on their order or position in an array. I am doing this for efficiency reasons the primary of which is that dropping keys (key-value pairs) is way more efficient than deleting those keys stored in an array based on first finding their positions.

Comment: It would be good provide an example that we can use as a benchmark since this is apparently a question about finding a function that performs better than one that you already have. You can generate the association programmatically and provide the code. Then provide a code that uses `AbsoluteTiming` to find out how fast the function you found is, and then we can see if we can do better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
GetKey[assoc_, index_] := First @ Keys @ Take[assoc, {index}]
```

Your first example:

```
assoc = <|{1,1} -> 2, {1,2} -> 3, {2,1}->4, {2,2}->5|>;

GetKey[assoc, 1]
GetKey[assoc, 4]
```

> {1, 1}
>
> {2, 2}

Your large example:

```
a = 1024*1024;
keys = Table[i, {i, a}];
values = RandomReal[{0, 1000000}, {a}];
assoc = Association[MapThread[Rule, {keys, values}]];

AbsoluteTiming[Keys[assoc][[10000]]]
AbsoluteTiming[GetKey[assoc, 10000]]
```

> {0.373301, 10000}
>
> {0.003779, 10000}

Comment: Thanks a lot. I failed to realize/recall that Take can be used on associations.

Answer (score 11):

This is one of those questions where I suspect it wasn't put enough thought in the data-structures. You use associations for fast access to values based on a key. The association data structure is just not optimized for what you try to do.

Nevertheless, I believe Carl's solution is already very good if you want a function that purely works on your association. If you need to access the same association very often, I would prefer to extract the keys and directly access them. A simple function could look like this:

```
KeyGet[a_Association] := Module[{keys = Keys[a]},
  KeyGet[i_Integer] := keys[[i]]
]
```

You use it by initializing it once with your association and then you provide only the integers (or ranges).

```
assoc = Association @@ Flatten@Table[{x, y} -> RandomInteger[100], {x, 1024}, {y, 1024}];

KeyGet[assoc];
KeyGet[1234]
KeyGet[{1,10,34}]
KeyGet[45;;100]
```

The first call of `KeyGet` needs about 0.44 seconds here. As soon as you need to access several thousand indices, it will be faster than using `Take` like in Carls example, but in general, I would prefer his solution.

Comment: The problem with this code as written is that you can only use it for one assoc at a time. But instead, you can return a pure function: `KeyGet[a_Association] := Module[{keys = Keys[a]},Function[i, keys[[i]]]]`, in which case you can use it on any number of assocs as the same time.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, I was aware of that. I didn't know how large the real application of the OP was. His large example was 1024^2 keys. If his real application is 1024^3, then we are already dealing with GB of keys. That was the reason I didn't present a solution returning a pure function with all keys.

Comment: @Leonid My only point here was that (a) I'm not sure he is dealing with the right data-structure in the first place and (b) that holding the keys separately in a list increases speed. Btw, I haven't forgotten your email and the draft of about 2 pages lies around for 2 weeks. I really have much to say and I want to answer each point. Now I have some free days and you will get it soon.

Comment: *"Btw, I haven't forgotten your email and the draft of about 2 pages lies around for 2 weeks"* - no worries at all, please take your time. Everyone is busy as hell these days. Somehow I am having a hard time realizing that another month passed by, time flies :).

Comment: @halirutan But the problem is that my association randomly gets KeyDroppedFrom very often, which is why I am using an association in the first place (it's faster to drop keys from an association than to search for the position of an entry in a list and delete it). So I think your static KeyGet function will not work for me as is.

Comment: @Iconoclast Then you should definitely go with Carl's solution. Accessing a single index with `Take` is almost as fast as doing `assoc[[index]]`. Only the access to a normal list would be vastly faster, but then you are back to your old problem of managing drop or insert if your association is not final.

Answer (score 6):

[Refresh your memory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2450/121) about how `Part` works and then observe:

```
assoc = <|{1, 1} -> 2, {1, 2} -> 3, {2, 1} -> 4, {2, 2} -> 5|>;

assoc[[{1}]]

assoc[[{4}]]
```

> ```
> <|{1, 1} -> 2|>
>
> <|{2, 2} -> 5|>
> ```

This is equivalent to `Take[assoc, {i}]` and syntactically shorter.  So I would write:

```
getKey[a_Association, p_Integer] := a[[{p}]] // Keys // First
```