# Inverting replace direction

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I just have a simple problem. I have a list such that,

```
rep = { a1 -> b1, a2 -> b2, a3 -> b3};
```

I want to invert replace direction such that,

```
{ b1 -> a1, b2 -> a2, b3 -> a3}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{a1 -> b1, a2 -> b2, a3 -> b3}  /.  Rule[x_, y_] -> Rule[y, x]
```

Comment: You should be using `:>` rather than `->` here, in case of assignments to `x` or `y`.

Answer (score 14):

When we have a long list of rules it would be resonable choosing a functional approach, which is much faster than  rule based one. In such cases consider e.g.

```
Reverse /@ rep
```

Sometimes it would be more efficient using `Transpose` twice than `Map` once, e.g.

```
Rule @@@ Transpose @ Reverse @ Transpose[ List @@@ rep]
```

Nonetheless ususally we need not to play with long lists and a simple pattern matching is quite sufficient, and so another approach might be e.g.

```
rep /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[b, a]
```

> ```
>  {b1 -> a1, b2 -> a2, b3 -> a3}
> ```

Mind using `RuleDelayed` in cases when it matters instead of `Rule`.

Answer (score 12):

#### Part

[`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) is a general approach to this kind of reordering challenge:

```
rep = {a1 -> b1, a2 -> b2, a3 -> b3};

rep[[All, {2, 1}]]
```

> ```
> {b1 -> a1, b2 -> a2, b3 -> a3}
> ```

Reference:

- [Head and everything except Head?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/121)

#### Reverse

Also there is a faster form of [`Reverse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html):

```
Reverse[rep, 2]
```

> ```
> {b1 -> a1, b2 -> a2, b3 -> a3}
> ```

#### Slot / Function

[`Slot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) notation is compact though performance tends to be less than the options above:

```
#2 -> # & @@@ rep
```

> ```
> {b1 -> a1, b2 -> a2, b3 -> a3}
> ```

Noteworthy is that unlike `Part` and `Reverse` this *replaces* heads.  For example if you have a mixed list of `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`:

```
rep = {a1 -> b1, a2 :> b2, a3 -> b3};

#2 -> # & @@@ rep
rep[[All, {2, 1}]]
```

> ```
> {b1 -> a1, b2 -> a2, b3 -> a3}
>
> {b1 -> a1, b2 :> a2, b3 -> a3}
> ```

#### Performance

Comparative timings with a large list of rules:

```
rep =
  Rule @@@ RandomInteger[1*^7, {1*^6, 2}];

rep /. (x_ -> y_) :> (y -> x); // RepeatedTiming
#2 -> # & @@@ rep;             // RepeatedTiming
Reverse /@ rep;                // RepeatedTiming
rep[[All, {2, 1}]];            // RepeatedTiming
Reverse[rep, 2];               // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.62, Null}
>
> {0.60, Null}
>
> {0.475, Null}
>
> {0.346, Null}
>
> {0.334, Null}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to join in on all of the fun:

```
Rule[Last@#,First@#]&/@rep
```

> Same output.